# How can I prevent strcpy() being optimised

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

I'm following an example in the book Hacking: The Art of Exploitation and I am getting different results to the book.

It seems that the strcpy() function in the example compiles to an instruction like:

```
0x802384c5 <main+27>: call 0x80482C4 <strcpy@plt>
```

whereas when I compile the same program it removes the call to the library and replaces it with a series of mov instructions:

```
0x8048475 <main+25>: mov    DWORD PTR [eax],0x6c6c6548
0x804847b <main+31>: mov    DWORD PTR [eax+0x4],0x6f57206f
0x8048482 <main+38>: mov    DWORD PTR [eax+0x8],0x21646c72
0x8048489 <main+45>: mov    WORD PTR [eax+0xc],0xa
```

I understand that the compiler can make various optimizations, but even though it's the default I've even tried compiling it with -O0 which is supposed to prevent optimisations.

How can I compile the code so it references the external library?

I've not done any C or assembly since uni, so be gentle with me :)

Comment: That's interesting.  You are copying the string literal `"Hello World!\n"`.  It seems that it has been converted to a bunch of integers and the loop has been unrolled, instead of a function call made.  This is purely a comment, as I don't know how to stop that from happening.

Comment: I don't know if the compiler will fall for it, but you could try defining your own function: `char *(*volatile mystrcpy)(char*,const char*) = strcpy;`

Comment: I think GCC has an option to "disable builtins", or something to that effect. Have a look for that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Paddy - the compiler was too smart. It compiled to something a little different to the original, but no function call. Kerrek - You were spot on using -fno-builtin got it compiling to 0x80484b0 <main+36>: call   0x8048370 <strcpy@plt>. If you want to put it down in an answer I will happily mark it correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With GCC, you can use the `-fno-builtin` (disable all builtins) or `-fno-builtin-strcpy` (just disable builtin `strcpy`).