# Trouble debugging functions in linked libraries with gdb

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I'm doing a bit of reading about gdb, and I'm having trouble getting gdb (I'm running 7.11.1) to debug a function from a library.
The sample code used to learn about the debugger is quite simple:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char str_a[20];

    strcpy(str_a, "Hello, world!\n");
    printf(str_a);
}
```

I compiled it with debugging symbols enabled, fired up GDB, and set some breakpoints:

```
(gdb) list
1   #include <stdio.h>
2   #include <string.h>
3   
4   int main() {
5       char str_a[20];
6   
7       strcpy(str_a, "Hello, world!\n");
8       printf(str_a);
9   }
(gdb) break 7
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4005ad: file char_array2.c, line 7.
(gdb) break strcpy
Function "strcpy" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
Breakpoint 2 (strcpy) pending.
(gdb) break 8
Breakpoint 3 at 0x4005cf: file char_array2.c, line 8.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/david/hacking_the_art_of_exploitation/Chapter_2/char_array2 

Breakpoint 1, main () at char_array2.c:7
7       strcpy(str_a, "Hello, world!\n");
(gdb) continue
Continuing.

Breakpoint 3, main () at char_array2.c:8
8       printf(str_a);
(gdb) continue
Continuing.
Hello, world!
[Inferior 1 (process 7061) exited normally]
```

As you can see, the debugger never descends into the strcpy function.

I've tried adding set stop-on-solib-events 1 to my .gdbinit.  This leads to different but still undesirable results:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/david/hacking_the_art_of_exploitation/Chapter_2/char_array2 
Stopped due to shared library event (no libraries added or removed)
```

I'm at a bit of a loss here.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why do you want to debug the `strcpy` function? Isn't it enough to see the result of the call? Like printing the contents of `str_a` from inside the debugger? What is the problem you *actually* have?

Comment: Also note that the compiler might not even *call* a "strcpy" function, it might replace it with highly optimized inline-code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Off topic but, when you say the compiler might optimize library call with inline-code that's neat! Can you provide a reference to that? I'm interest on that aspect of compiler optimization?

Comment: @Miket25: Compile `include <string.h>` / `void foo(int *a, int *b) { memcpy(a, b, sizeof *a); }` with full optimzation (-O3 with GCC) and assembly output (-S with GCC). With any good compiler, the resulting assembly will not have a call to `memcpy` but rather a load instruction and a store instruction, or a memory move instruction if the architecture has one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent strcpy() being optimised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059044/how-can-i-prevent-strcpy-being-optimised).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need the libc-dbg package and the libc source package for debugging a libc function. On Ubuntu you can install it via

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dbg
mkdir ~/libc ; cd ~/libc
apt-get source libc6
```